# Use jquery to hide custom modal when the user clicks outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Duplicate:**

Yes it is. Below is the references which I searched on stack overflow.

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264483/use-jquery-to-hide-div-when-click-outside-it-but-allow-propagation-of-events)

[Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

[Reference 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396391/hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it-using-jquery)

[Reference 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983655/how-to-hide-a-div-in-backbone-when-user-clicks-outside-of-div)

**What I am looking for:**

Actually I am making custom modal without using bootstrap. Overall my code is working fine and below is the live example of it:

```
$(window).click(function(e){
    let classname = e.target.className;
    if(classname == "ah-modal-wrapper") {
    e.target.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayopnn7/)

Problem is when I select my inner text of modal and release my selection outside from modal its hide / close the modal. But my need is when I click outside of a modal then modal should closed immediately. Which is working fine. but I don't want that modal closed while releasing the mouse click outside from modal.

For more clearance please review below example:

[Bootstrap Modal Example](http://www.bootstrap-tutorials.com/bootstrap4tutorials/Bootstrap-4-Modal-Large-Small-Modals.php)

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code:

```
$('.ah-modal-wrapper').on('mousedown', function(e) {    
    $(this).hide();
});

$('.ah-modal').on('mousedown', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Also updated [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayopnn7/2/)

Comment: outside the modal I want click event closed the modal. Not mouse down. As the bootstrap example is the best example of what I want.

Comment: Why is it important to using `click` instead of any other event?

Comment: BTW if you like `click` event, you can change the code to `click, mousedown`, then the `click` event also will be added

Comment: Because it is the standard of modal on most popular sites like bootstrap and facebook etc. So thats why I want this without using bootstrap.

Comment: If you need something standard, you should use `bootstrap` modal instead of re-creating something that is already created for you

Comment: I agreed with you. But why I need to use bootstrap only for modal? I created my own theme without using bootstrap and I just want to use modal standard and for that I load whole Library of bootstrap.

Comment: As I said you can add `click` event too, but I don't think using `click` is standard way, you should use any event that works for you, also there is tons of `jQuery` plugins that implemented modal in standard way.

Comment: As I said why I need  to use other libraries only for custom modal. Below I posted my answer. Take a look only 4 lines of code solve my answer. But I appreciate your answer on my post. Thanks for your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code (answer) of my own question.

```
let istextSelected = false;
    $(window).click(function(e){
        let classname = e.target.className;
        if(classname == "ah-modal-wrapper") {
            if(istextSelected == false) {
                e.target.style.display = 'none';
            }
        istextSelected = false;
    }
});

$(".ah-modal").on('mousedown',function(e){
   istextSelected = true;
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayopnn7/4/)

Comment: BTW, adding `click` event on `document` decreasing the performance, I think you need to change the solution, don't use my code, but change the solution, just take a look on some plugin's source to find out how to deal with this problem.

Comment: About let I know that it is not run on mostly every browser. But only in my Fiddle example I am using it. second thing is that about decreasing the performance I searched over a internet and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251266/does-performance-suffer-if-i-attach-onclick-events-to-body)